# Is LINQ extension method Where guaranteed to preserve order?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list of messages in a publish/subscribe architecture, I assume it is reasonable to use IEnumerable.Where on an underlying List to retrieve particular messages and trust the order of the messages?

Comment: Note that there is not actually any such method as `IEnumerable.Where`. There is an `Enumerable.Where` extension method which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`. But it's entirely possible that a given LINQ query will use something different for a given enumerable type! And it can be implemented in an order-preserving or non-order-preserving manner.

Comment: I know it's not a member but an extension method. It was just easier to write and I assume everybody knows about the linq extension methods.

Comment: Just remember that a given enumerable type might define its own `Where()` method, which might be used in place of `Enumerable.Where()`, depending on the type of the reference you're enumerating.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `Enumerable.Where` extension method will, but the `Queryable.Where` extension method won't.

`Enumerable.Where` has to preserve the order, since it streams the results and there is no cache (and no logic in caching results).

`Queryable.Where`, on the other hand, translates the given call to something the underlying data source will understand and there is no guarantee about the ordering what so ever. This effect can be observed easily when working with relational databases. The addition of a `where` clause can let the database pick another index, which can change the ordering of the results. Without an explicit `order by` clause, the selected index will typically determine the ordering of the results.

Comment: Indeed, LINQ to Entities is documented to *not* preserve order after a `.Where()`

Comment: Whereas it's true that `Enumerable.Where` currently preserves order, I don't see anything in the interface documentation that guarantees it will. And, of course, all bets are off if you're using `ParallelEnumerable`.

Comment: @Jim: I agree the documentation of `Enumerable.Where` doesn't state it will preserve order, but I think it's safe to assume it will always preserve ordering, because it would still be a pretty big behavioral change that a lot of developers depend upon.

Answer (score 7):

For Linq to Objects / `IEnumerable` this is true - order will be maintained - for `IQueryable` providers it depends on the provider, many providers do not maintain order.

It looks like this fact (maintaining order) is not documented on MSDN though, so I would consider it an implementation detail that - although unlikely - might change in the future.

Comment: Is the interface for `IEnumerable` documented to preserve order? Or do we just "know" it will?

Comment: @Jim, `IEnumerable` has no `Where` at all. It's an extension method and a query pattern, but it's not a member of the interface.

Comment: @CraigStuntz: Fine. `Enumerable.Where`, then. I don't see documentation that says it will preserve order.